# Error inserting data into MariaDB using the Python requests module

Tags: python, mariadb

I am trying to create a Python script that will fill some information in the database. For the server side I have used PHP and when I try to submit information using a browser, it works. But when I try to do it using the below Python script, it doesn't.

```
import requests

url_insert = 'http://192.168.1.100/data.php'

data_insert = {'fullname':'spiderman',
    'ssn':'1234',
    'dept':'Security',
    'salary':10000,
    'homeaddress':'New York',
    'btn_save':'Save'}

req = requests.post(url_insert, data = data_insert)
print(req.text)
```

I get the following error:

```
INSERT INTO emp_record (ename, ssn, dept, salary, homeaddress) VALUES ('', '', '', , '')<br>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' '')'
```

The code for data.php is:

```
<?php
require("database.php");

if (isset($_POST["btn_save"])) {
    $fullname = $_POST["fullname"];
    $ssn = $_POST["ssn"];
    $dept = $_POST["dept"];
    $salary = $_POST["salary"];
    $homeaddress = $_POST["homeaddress"];

    echo $fullname . "<br>";
    echo $ssn . "<br>";
    echo $dept . "<br>";
    echo $salary . "<br>";
    echo $homeaddress . "<br>";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO emp_record (ename, ssn, dept, salary, homeaddress)
        VALUES ('$fullname', '$ssn', '$dept', $salary, '$homeaddress')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>
```

This shows the contents of the database connection file:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "employees";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "Connected Successfully." . "<br>";
}
```

And the following is the contents of the index.php file which contains the HTML form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>RETRIEVE DATA</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="data.php" method="POST">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" value="" placeholder="FullName">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="id">Social Security Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="ssn" id="ssn" value="" placeholder="Social Security Number">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="id">Department</label>
        <input type="text" name="dept" id="dept" value="" placeholder="Department">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="id">Salary</label>
        <input type="text" name="salary" id="salary" value="" placeholder="Salary">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="id">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="homeaddress" id="homeaddress" value="" placeholder="Address">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="btn_save" value="Save">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why it is giving me database related error. Because when I try to enter data using a browser, it gets saved inside the database table.

Comment: Aside: Your PHP code is _**wide open** to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)_. Don't build queries by sticking strings together or interpolating values. Instead, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: remove the actual URL to your endpoint if it is in fact the real one. the code you show is vulnerable to SQL injection as @Chris mentions